# Packet analysing in wireshark - How to distinguish HTTP protocol from TCP

Tags: c, data-analysis, wireshark, pcap

I am working on a school project, in which I have to analyze .pcap files in C language using the libcap library. I am new to networking, however I do know that TCP is on the layer 4 and HTTP is on the 7th layer in the OSI model. I want to sort HTTP packets, and print out the source/destination ports but I'm a little confused how to distinguish HTTP protocols from TCP protocols.
Here is an example, which I don't understand:

EDIT: Here is another example, where the source port is 80, the length is 100. The 54th byte is 48, which is the same as for a HTTP 1.1 response packet. It is a TCP.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQs6v.png

The destination port here is 80, which is HTTP. However wireshark does not list this packet as a HTTP protocol, it is just TCP.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsVuO.png
Me question is how to determine based on bytes if the packet is a HTTP protocol or just a TCP protocol?

Comment: The packet you have shown is not a HTTP packet. It has `Len: 0` which indicates it is an ACK only packet. To  determine whether it is HTTP, need to parse the payload to see if it has valid data as defined by the HTTP specification.

Comment: I still don't get it, i edited the post.

Comment: The packet you have shown in `RQs6v.png` does appear to be a HTTP packet. Where does wireshark say it isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot determine if a packet is HTTP or not just by looking at its headers. HTTP is application level, if you want to identify an HTTP stream you will have to check the innermost payload of the packet. In other words, HTTP packets are distinguishable just by looking at what comes after the TCP header. Wireshark already does this for you and marks packets that look like HTTP as such. You can filter packets identified as HTTP by Wireshark by simply typing `http` in the filter bar at the top.

In your case, the packet you show has Length = 0, so there really isn't anything to analyze other than the various headers of the different layers. The packet is not HTTP.

Determining HTTP traffic "based on bytes" can be done by looking at the payload: HTTP requests and responses have known formats. For example HTTP 1.1 requests start with `<METHOD> <URI> HTTP/1.1\r\n`, and responses with `HTTP/1.1 <CODE> <MSG>\r\n`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it is still not clear how can I distinguish two packets just based on bytes. I edited the post and added another example.

Comment: @Zsolti you are looking at the headers of the packet. As I said you ***cannot*** distinguish an HTTP packet just by looking at the header. You need to look at the TCP payload. Your second example shows no payload at all (lan: 0)!